# Workaround for merge using update in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a scenario where I am trying to insert and update some rows in my informix table. I am using hibernate.
I have observed that calling merge operations is not as efficient as calling update operations.
But I can't always use update operation as we may have a scenario where a particular item is inserted and then updated later. In this case if I use update operation then I get NonUniqueObjectException (different object with same identifier is already in the session). 
I wrote a workaround for that and it seems to be working. I want to know if there is any problems with the below code which I may face in future or if I am missing something.

I have some way which tells me that a particular record needs to be updated or inserted.

My update code looks like this:

```
try{
session.update(entity);
}
catch(Exception e){
session.merge(entity);
}
```

I know that I am going to have very less scenario where the code in catch block will be executed so I am okay with this. Is this going to cause some unexpected problems?

Please keep in mind that I don't wanna use merge operation unless absolutely necessary since merge operations calls a select query before performing update and it is causing me performance issue.

Comment: Yes, it's going to cause unexpected problems. Hibernate exception are unrecoverable. The only safe thing to do when you get  one is to rollback the transaction and close the session.

Comment: If that's the case then is there any other way to do what I am doing. I basically want to call update instead of merge wherever possible and if not possible only then I want to call merge.